# Angular2 i18n : HTML markup in translations?

Tags: angular, internationalization

I've implemented i18n in my Angular2 application, all is set up. The only thing I'm struggling with is HTML markup in my translations.

E.g. I have a header like this:

```
<h3>Header with a <a href="#">link</a></h3>
```

If I add the i18n attribute to the h3, the translation will contain the HTML references. Most of the XLF management tools out there seem to struggle with this, they don't provide proper support to manage this.
So I could fix this by changing it to:

```
<h3><span i18n>Header with a </span><a href="#" i18n>link</a></h3>
```

But that doesn't seem right.

Additionally, I've got a page with our T&C with a lot of HTML mark up. Right now I've added the i18n element to the top, but all formatting is lost when translating.

Or am I using the wrong tools? I have tried a lot out there, none of them manages this well.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: We've switched to XMB, and we're using Text United. That works really well, even for very big HTML chunks of content (like our T&C). Only issue is that Text United does not generate an XTB (but just an XMB), but that's an easy thing to do; just a string-replacement to get from XMB to XTB.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to "trust" to the HTML from localization string.
Import this pipe : https://gist.github.com/Bloggerschmidt/d1c635a9d8ca6d2d8804a16822b72e4e

Usage :

```
<div [innerHTML] = "'loc_key' | translate | sanitizeHtml"></div>
```